# sass mixin for genrating classes

Tags: sass, mixins

I would like to generate a set of classes that looks like this:

```
.mr-s{
 margin-right: $space-s;
}

.mr-m{
 margin-right: $space-m;
}

.ml-s{
 margin-left: $space-s;
}

.ml-m{
 margin-left: $space-m;
}
```

So I'm trying to create a mixin for that but the compilation fails:

```
 $space-s: 0.8rem;
 $space-m: 1rem;
 $space-l: 2.4rem;

$margin-sizes: s m l;
@mixin margins($direction) {
  @each $size in $margin-sizes{
    .m#{$direction}-#{$size} {
        margin-#{$direction}: $space-#{$size};
  }
}
```

1. Is it even possible to create the variable name dynamically ($space-s,$space-m)?
2. It fails even if i use a fixed value for the size

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you put the `$` symbol to a word it converts it into a variable, therefore if you separate the elements of that word and add the `$` in a single section separated from the other with a space, they would become different elements.

The same does not happen with properties because what you are joining or canting are strings.

```
$space-s: 0.8rem;
$space-m: 1rem;
$space-l: 2.4rem;

$margin-sizes: s m l;

@mixin margins($direction) {
  @each $size in $margin-sizes{
    .m#{$direction}-#{$size} {
            margin-#{$direction}:$space-s;            
    }
        .m#{$direction}-#{$size} {
            margin-#{$direction}:$space-m;            
    }
        .m#{$direction}-#{$size} {
            margin-#{$direction}:$space-l;            
    }
    }
}

.myclass{
    @include margins(right);
}
```

The result would be this:

```
.class .mright-s {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
}
.class .mright-s {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.class .mright-s {
  margin-right: 2.4rem;
}
.class .mright-m {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
}
.class .mright-m {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.class .mright-m {
  margin-right: 2.4rem;
}
.class .mright-l {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
}
.class .mright-l {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.class .mright-l {
  margin-right: 2.4rem;
}
```